# Sending a file content to a server: Socket

Tags: c, sockets

My code reads from a file line by line and sends it to a server.

```
client.c

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    FILE* pFile;
    char* line = NULL;
    //char buffer[256];
    char* buffer;
    int len;



    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }



   pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","r");
   if (pFile==NULL)
   {
        printf("Error reading temp file\n");
        exit (1);
       }

    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    error("ERROR connecting");


//loop  
     while (!feof(pFile)) {
    //printf("Please enter the message: ");
    line = readLine(pFile, line);
    len=strlen(line);
    buffer= (char*) malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
    bzero(buffer,len);
    memcpy(buffer,line,len+1);
   // fgets(buffer,len,pFile);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);
    if (n < 0) 
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    free(buffer);    
    free(line); 
    }   



    buffer= (char*) malloc(2048*sizeof(char));   
    bzero(buffer,2048);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,2048);

    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);

    free(buffer);
    fclose (pFile);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

And

```
    /* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>



void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


 int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
 socklen_t clilen;
 char buffer[2048];
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
 int n;


 if (argc < 2) {
     fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
     exit(1);
 }


 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
    else
    printf("Socket connected\n");


 bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
 portno = atoi(argv[1]);
 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
 if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
          sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
          error("ERROR on binding");
 listen(sockfd,5);
 clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
 newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
             (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
             &clilen);
 if (newsockfd < 0) 
      error("ERROR on accept");

 printf("Data Receieved by client: \n");

  bzero(buffer,2048);
  n=read(newsockfd,buffer,2048);

    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);



  n = write(newsockfd,"Server received the message",18); 
  if (n < 0) 
      error("ERROR writing to socket");



 close(newsockfd);
 close(sockfd);
 return 0;
```

}

The problem is that the server reveives a few lines and misses a few. Not able to figure out what is wrong. Can some one help?

```
Client Side
[gaurav1.k@DELL-BUILD03 Socket]$ gcc -Wall client.c -o client.exe
[gaurav1.k@DELL-BUILD03 Socket]$ ./client.exe localhost 8000
I am line number One,am I?
Here comes line number Two.
Will you welcome, Line number Three? And I am your Friend.
I am here, It is me - Line number Four.
Hello All, I am line number Five, am I? Yes I am.
It is over, because I am line number six.
Server received th
[gaurav1.k@DELL-BUILD03 Socket]$

Server Side:
[gaurav1.k@DELL-BUILD03 Socket]$ gcc -Wall server.c -o server.exe
[gaurav1.k@DELL-BUILD03 Socket]$ ./server.exe 8000
Socket connected
Data Receieved by client:
I am line number One,am I?
[gaurav1.k@DELL-BUILD03 Socket]$
```

The content of file to be read is:

```
I am line number One,am I?
Here comes line number Two.
Will you welcome, Line number Three? And I am your Friend.
I am here, It is me - Line number Four.
Hello All, I am line number Five, am I? Yes I am.
It is over, because I am line number six.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is multiple `write` at the client side, but only one `read` at the server side. How?

For every line the client will `write` into the socket, that is multiple `write`(you are using `write` in a loop), but in server you are having one `read`, that is single `read`(no loop's, so it will read only the first line).

For first line, you are reading at server side. But for second line the client is writing, but your server have no read statement(first `read` is already executed). Due to this you wont receive the full message

A simple solution is write the whole file content at a time, not line by line and read it.

Try the below change also-

```
n = write(newsockfd,"Server received the message",50); // Increase the size
```

Answer (score 3):

For a scenario like this you usually want to implement a kind of communication protocol.

Most importantly, the server needs to know how many bytes it has to read to receive the whole content. So usually, you transfer the message size as the first part of your message (header). Then the server knows how many bytes to receive after that to consume the actual payload data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you don't check the result of the [read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) and [write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html) functions, which can fail in partial success states, indicating the number of bytes they've successfully transferred. In general, you need to wrap these functions in a loop that repeats until the entire buffer has been read/written.

Comment: This was so predictable from the title - I too went straight to the send/recv calls.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the failure to properly account for the returns from system calls, as described by other posters, there is:

```
bzero(buffer,2048);
n=read(newsockfd,buffer,2048)
..
printf("%s\n",buffer);
```

If the read() returns 2048 bytes, the printf can UB as it tries to find a non-existent null after the end of the buffer.  Either allocate/clear 2049 of read 2047, and even that will only work well for transferring plain ASCII text files, (ie files with no embedded nulls).